# I'm trying to trigger a Flow when a new email is received in an O365 Groups mailbox

Tags: power-automate

I am trying to trigger a Flow that identifies the attachment type (e.g. .pdf and .docx) and save it to a team site library if it's a valid attachment.  If not, it sends the "from" email address an email saying the attachment is invalid.  I have done this successfully for a site mailbox (created before Microsoft removed the ability to create site mailboxes in SP Online) and my personal mailbox, but I am getting the following error when using an O365 Group email inbox:

"message": "You are not authorized to perform this operation. This error can occur for sandbox (test) accounts or if OData operations are disabled by your Exchange server administrator."

Again, this error only occurs when triggering the Flow with:

[image: When a new email arrives]